# Improving search results obtained under "relevance" tab

Tags: feature-request, search

I've recently had occasion to ask several questions about [Selenium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29), and easily 50% of my search time was weeding out old answers which are no longer applicable due to changes to Selenium.

I'm not sure what algorithm is used to find "relevant" questions, but no matter how many upvotes a question/answer has, if it's from 2008, in a lot of cases, especially for young technology like Selenium, it's not going to be very relevant.

I understand that if the question is about, say, C or [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) or something, even older answers will remain relevant. So instead of rejigging that algorithm, would it be possible at least to list the search results under "relevance" in chronological order? The search results under "newest" almost never overlap with the "relevant" ones, so the ability to arrange just the "relevant" hits in chronological order would be useful.

Comment: If you want to exclude old posts, you can do that with a search parameter.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

Comment: Is there any way to make it default?